What eastern forest tree species is best suited as a cabin ridge beam?
Is there a specific species of Boreal forest tree that is best suited as a cabin ridge beam? I figure certain kinds of wood might be stronger/more rigid than others.
Location of site: Eastern Ontario.
Trees spotted:

Eastern white pine
Eastern hemlock
Eastern white cedar
American beech
Oak - species unknown


Each species has pros and cons. Historically, cabins are simply made from whatever trees are available and all of those have been used with great success.
Just be sure to have the wood dried as needed. Some species should be dried prior to use as they shrink/warp too much while drying.
Also, strength by wood species is known, but strength for your particular logs are not. Example: Beech is quite strong (almost as strong as oak), but tends to have many knots which weaken the beam.

I agree. If it's a matter of finding the one that offers the smallest required diameter, consult strength tables for each species.

Another way of phrasing it is, in addition to knowing the species you also need to know the grade of the material.  The Ontario Building code has strength tables in that will refer to standardize material dimensions, as well as species groups, and grades.  Off the top of my head I know that S-P-F (Spruce-Pine-Fir) has at least 3 grade categories.  Select Structural (SS), No1, and No2.  There may be more grades beyond No 2. but I do not recall off the top of my head.

Of the 3 softwoods mentioned, hemlock is the strongest, all else being equal. Pine is quite common in large beams because all else (such as tree size) may not be equal. But given a choice between "SPF" or hemlock, hemlock is the stronger frame. Cedar is significantly inferior for framing strength.
Eastern White Pine Eastern Hemlock Northern White Cedar
Both beech and oak are stronger than the softwoods, all else being equal.
Beech Red Oak White oak
Normally in vernacular architecture the wood members are vastly oversized from what tables with minimum sizes of graded lumber would suggest, since the lumber in question is normally not (officially) graded.
